# Android - Request to update to com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

I just got back from lunch. I didn't make any changes; gradle sync ran on its own and now I have this message.

Did anyone encounter that? I had that tomorrow, built again and everything ran smoothly. I'm stuck.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
```

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

Here my Gradle file, but really I don't get it T_T

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId '*****'
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 999999
    versionName "3.0.4"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.3'
compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Did you do what the error suggests?

Comment: Yes, but it since I'm using firebase that is in 9.6.1 - I'm afraid It's not going to work anymore - or to create side effect :-/
It seems to compile, but this is so weird?

Comment: *by updating the version of the google-services **plugin***

Comment: Side note, `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'` imports **the entire play services library**. You shouldn't do that, only import the modules you need

Comment: Awesome advice Tim, thanks!

Comment: I noticed that this library was requested while not needing it. Problem solved. For now.

Answer (score 0):

Upadate your Google Play Services from sdk tools.